# Why creating the elements with custom tags adds the xml namespace in the outerHTML in IE9 or 10 until the .find() method is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, dom

I have a jsfiddle that demonstrates the question:

http://jsfiddle.net/H6gML/8/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // this seems fine in IE9 and 10
    var $div = $("<div>");
    console.log("In IE, this <div> is just fine: " + $div[0].outerHTML);

    // this is weird in IE
    var $test = $("<test>");    
    console.log("However, this <test> has an xml tag prepended: \n" 
                + $test[0].outerHTML);    
    $test.find("test");    
    console.log("Now, it does not: \n" + $test[0].outerHTML);    
    console.log("Why does this behave this way?");
});
```

Why does this happen? It doesn't happen in Chrome or Firefox. Is there a better way to fix this than to call `.find("test")` on the object?

## Edit

To clarify, I'm not asking why the xml tag is added, rather, I'm wondering why the .find() call get's rid of it. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Put the code into the question, not just in jsFiddle.  It's not that long.

Comment: Could it have something to do with it not being a valid HTML tag?

Comment: The XML tag is probably added because IE is pretty sure it's XML, as there is no valid HTML tag called "test".

Comment: `$test.find("test");` doesn't make sense...

Comment: if `var $test = $('<test>')` makes jQuery return a structure like `<xml><test></test>`, the xml tag is the parent element, so `$test` is really an object containing the xml tag and it's children, so doing `$test.find('test')` returns any children matching that selector, thus returning your `<test>` tag.

Comment: @adeneo - sure, that's returning... but does find also assign? notice there is no `$test = $test.find("test");`

Comment: Do you get any different results if you use `$("<test />");` instead?

Comment: How about `$.parseHTML("<text>")`? that's the recommended way of generating html from text with jquery in more modern versions anyway, it gets rid of the guesswork.

Comment: this feels like a bug. It's neither a XML processing-instruction nor an element.

Comment: Yes, definitely a bug. `.find()` shouldn't change the value of `$test`

Comment: Using `document.createElement('test')` also returns the xml tag, so no suprise there, that is IE, but why find() would somehow change the collection is strange, but it does do a lot of stuff [internally](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.find), replacing etc. so it probably cleans the collection somehow.

Comment: Do it this way `var $test = $("<html><test/></html>");` here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v5UrP/

Comment: @PSL - and the question was - why does calling find() on the selection suddenly remove the xml tag ?

Comment: @adeneo yeah thats the second part of the question.. :) need to dig in the find method of jquery...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does this happen? It doesn't happen in Chrome or Firefox. Is there a better way to fix this than to call .find("test") on the object

It is the IE causing the issue while doing `document.createElement` on an unknown html element type. It thinks it is an XML node and adds the xml namespace prefixed `<?XML:NAMESPACE PREFIX = PUBLIC NS = "URN:COMPONENT" />`. Instead if you try to make it explicit to mention that it is an html element, this issue doesn't happen.

Try:

```
 var $test = $("<html><test/></html>");
```

The issue no longer occurs.

> To clarify, I'm not asking why the xml tag is added, rather, I'm wondering why the .find() call get's rid of it. It doesn't make sense to me.

Now, when you do a find, jquery internally uses `context.getElementsByTagName` or (similar based on the type whether it is a class or a tag or id etc..) which means it does this operation on the element `test`. So in IE when you do that it probably internally resolves the fact that you are trying to perform the operation on an html element and not an xml element and it changes the document type for the underlying context(But i don't know why it changes the parent context though rather than just returning a match). You can check this out by this simple example as well.

```
var $test = document.createElement("test");    
console.log("However, this <test> has an xml tag prepended: \n" 
            + $test.outerHTML);  
$test.getElementsByTagName("test");
console.log("Now, it does not: \n" + $test.outerHTML);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K72vD/)**

**Update**

Here is a [documented way of defining the custom elements](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/)

> The custom element type identifies a custom element interface and is a sequence of characters that must match the NCName production and contain a U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS character. The custom element type must not be one of the following values:
>   **annotation-xml,
>   color-profile,
>   font-face,
>   font-face-src,
>   font-face-uri,
>   font-face-format,
>   font-face-name,
>   missing-glyph**

So according to this had your tag name been `somename-test` ex:- `custom-test` IE recognizes it and it works as expected.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WYVx8/)**